# Does DSE search support json queries through the HTTP API (if not, can it be enabled?)

Tags: json, solr, datastax-enterprise, faceted-search

In the newer versions of Solr, you can pass in json queries through the HTTP API by either just passing it in as the data, or by using "query?json={json doc here}".

We noticed in the DSE version, it's using "select" as the handler and not "query" (not sure if they are different), but attempting to pass in a select?json={"q":"*:*"} or select?json={"query":"*:*"} always yields no results and a curl just passing those also yields no results. It looks like it's a supported feature based on : http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchJSON.html, but not sure if it includes json facets like: http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/.

The main reason we want to use it is the advanced sub-faceting (we need pivot facets with date range groupings), and we'd prefer to do it over the http api for a variety of reasons.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON facet API is introduced in Solr 5.1.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7214

The latest DSE as of today ships Solr 4.10. This API is not yet supported.